# Why isn't pydantic v2 finding SettingsSourceCallable?

Tags: python, pip, pydantic

I'm looking at the migration guide and documentation: https://docs.pydantic.dev/2.4/migration/#basesettings-has-moved-to-pydantic-settings

I can't seem to find where to locate `SettingsSourceCallable`

My pipeline is breaking for this import:
 `from pydantic.env_settings import SettingsSourceCallable`

Error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'SettingsSourceCallable'
from 'pydantic.env_settings' (/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pydantic/env_settings.py)
```

requirements.txt file:

```
fastapi~=0.103.2
pydantic~=2.4.2 
uvicorn[standard]~=0.23.2
aiohttp~=3.8.3
PyJWT~=1.7.1
requests~=2.27.1
starlette~=0.27.0
starlette-context~=0.3.6
jose
python-jose-cryptodome
pytest~=7.1.2
pytest-asyncio~=0.19.0
pytest-cov~=3.0.0
aioresponses~=0.7.3
```

Comment: `SettingsSourceCallable` is a `Callable` of `BaseSettings`. This has been moved to the package `Pydantic-settings`. See https://pypi.org/project/pydantic-settings/